# EmberJS - Template conditional with parameters

Tags: templates, ember.js, helper, conditional-statements

Within my template, I am iterating over an array that's in a model.
For simplicity, I'll use the following example:

```
{{#each user in appModel.users}}
```

Now, I am trying to display elements of `user` if the user is in a certain group.
I have `App.Group` as a model, that has a method for checking if a user is in the group.  This method takes a parameter, user.

So,

```
{{group.has_user user}}
```

Where `group` is a specific instance of `App.Group`, would return either true or false if the user's ID was found in the group's list of ID's.

I am trying to find a way to use this method as a template conditional.  Like so:

```
{{#if group.has_user user}}
  <block>
{{/if}}
```

To put it all together:

```
{{#each user in appModel.users}}
  {{#if group.has_user user}}
    <block displaying user data>
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Thus, the desired effect of displaying users of the group would be achieved.  The problem is the conditional `{{#if}}` helper cannot take a parameter with the method.

I tried to use a custom register helper, but I couldn't find a way to pass model attributes.  If I used the helper in my template like so:

```
{{#ifUserInGroup user.id group.id}}
```

I would get the strings 'user.id' and 'group.id' as the passed parameters.  The helper is written like so:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('ifUserInGroup', function(val1, val2, options){
   //This is where I would get the models, but val1 and val2 are strings, not id's...
});
```

If anyone knows of a way to use the method in a conditional, or how to pass actual values to the helper, please help me out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT:** As of version 1.0 of ember, this solution do not work any longer.

To build on my registered helper from my original post, and with some help from Vinothbabu, I managed to get something working.

What I was missing, was `Ember.Handlebars.get(root, path, options)`

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('ifUserInGroup', function(user, group, options){
    user = Ember.Handlebars.get(this, user, options);
    group = Ember.Handlebars.get(this, group, options); 
    if (group.has_user(user)) {
        return options.fn(this);
    } else {
        return options.inverse(this);
    }
});
```

With that function, I could get the actual bound data instead of strings passed to the helper.

So,

```
{{#each user in users}}
  {{#ifUserInGroup user.id some_group.id}}
    <block displaying user data>
  {{/ifUserInGroup}}
{{/each}}
```

where `users` is an array property of the app model, and `some_group` is an `App.Group` instance property of the app model, would display a block for each user that is in the group.

Comment: block helpers aren't supported in ember... http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.html#method_registerBoundHelper

Comment: Correct.  It used to, but sadly as of version 1.0, it does not.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code and let me know if it works.

```
{{#each group in model}}
   {{#if group.has_user}}
      <block>
   {{/if}}
{{else}]
    <block>
{{/each}}
```

Then inside your model class, retrieve the data something like this.

```
App.YourModelClass = Ember.Model.extend({
     has_user:function(){
        var value = this.get('user');
     }
});
```

you can also use the `valueBinding` property to bind your properties to your model classes, something like this below.

```
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="yourProp"}}
```

**Update as requested**

Below is your **template** changes...

```
 {{#ifUserInGroup user group}}
    yes
   {{else}}
    no
 {{/ifUserInGroup}}
```

Below is your **handlebar** helper.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifUserInGroup', function (user, group, options) {
    if (typeof group[user] != 'undefined') {
        return options.fn(this);
    } else {
        return options.inverse(this);
    }
});
```

Below is a **fiddle** for you. 
http://jsfiddle.net/R8u6g/12/

Comment: The problem with this is you are displaying the groups that the current user is belonged to.  What I need is a list of users (that may not be the current user) that are in a particular group.  Maybe my original post was not clear; I'll add more detail.

Comment: I managed to get it going.  Your post helped me get there, but there was one thing missing.  You see, in your fiddle, you passed the actual name of the group, so you could find the group in the registered helper simply by looking up the name.  I was looking to find if a user was in a group by passing two bound properties, like in my original post where I passed user.id and group.id to ifUserInGroup.  Passing that in your fiddle would result in 'user.id' and 'group.id' being used by the registered helper as strings.  The key was to use Ember.Handlebars.get.  I'll show how I did it another post.